# Performing search in StackExchange.Redis

Tags: c#, redis, stackexchange.redis

I'm using Stack Exchange .Net Redis provider to store and retrieve values. I would like to know how can I search for certain records inside Redis (like any database, search needs to be executed in Redis instance not in .Net application)

Example:

```
public class Employee
{
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
    public int Age { get; set; }
    public int Salary {get;set;}
}
```

If I have 100,000 records of employees stored as .Net "`List<Employee> lstEmployee = new List<Employee>();`" in Redis cache server and would like to fetch only the record whose age >50 and salary > 5000, how should I code for it?

Disclosure: I'm just getting started with Redis using [this example](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn690521.aspx).

Comment: The link has moved. Currently you can get the REDIS documentation from Microsoft here: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-cache-for-redis/

Answer (score 8):

First, a "cache server" is not intended to be used as a queryable store. If we assume instead that you mean simply a nosql backend, then ... well, frankly, that doesn't sound like the sort of query I would try and do via redis. The point of redis is that you *build whatever indexes you need yourself*. If you want ordered range queries (the age / salary), then a sorted set and ZRANGEBYSCORE is probably a viable option; however, intersecting these two queries is more difficult. You could try asking the same question ib the redisdb google-group, but just as a general redis question - not specific to any client library such as SE.Redis. If the operations exist ib redis, *then* you can use the client library to invoke them.

I'm wondering, however, whether "elastic" might be a better option for what you describe.

Comment: What would be a good choice of a persistent NoSQL store, that offers full versatile search capabilities, to work with .NET Core?

Comment: @Shimmy define "versatile search capabilities"? For example, it may be that RediSearch (a module that you can run inside the redis server) meets your needs - or that might be a completely inappropriate tool!

Comment: I believe I was referring to Document DB. I'm still not sure which one to use. I wish there would have been a MIT/BSD licensed one. Mongo/Raven are GPL.